# Exporting animated low poly water into Unity

Tags: animation, export, unity

Recently I created low poly terrain with river in the middle. I want to import it into Unity, but I can't do it properly.
I used vertex groups to connect few vertices together and used shape keys to create waves animation (I just move vertices from vertex group up and down).

When I imported it into Unity there was no animation. Should I do this in any different way to work or did I just messed up somethig with importing? Please note that I'm still learning Blender and Unity, and I could make some stupid mistakes.